# Format a nested list in place

Tags: python

I have the following list of tuples --

```
[('one',[1,2,5,3,9,8]), ('two',[9,8,5,1])]
```

And need to sort the nested list, while keeping the ordering of the tuples as is --

```
[('one',[1,2,3,5,8,9]), ('two',[1,5,8,9])]
```

The way that I am currently doing this is with a `for` loop --

```
list_of_tuples = [('one',[1,2,5,3,9,8]), ('two',[9,8,5,1])]

sorted_list_of_tuples = []
for item1, item2 in list_of_tuples:
    sorted_list_of_tuples.append((item1, sorted(item2))
```

Is there an easier way to do this in one line? Thank you.

Comment: Couldn't you just call sort on each of the inner lists?  Why do you _need_ to do this in a single line?

Comment: Doesn't have to be one line: mine just seemed a bit verbose.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Doesn't get much easier:

```
for t in list_of_tuples:
    t[1].sort()
```

Answer (score 1):

Just us a list comprehension.

```
sorted_list = [(x[0],sorted(x[1])) for x in list_of_tuples]
```